# Use SPQuery or REST API to join two lists

Tags: rest, custom-list, spquery, joined-view

I am using SP 2013 and trying to joint two lists which are linked through a lookup field in the second list. I have tried several things like XML and SpSiteDataQuery but I am not familiar with using C#. I just know using javascript and jquery in SP. So what should I use in SP2013 to join the lists and present their data?

Can I use SPQuery or REST API for this?
I found examples here:

[Sharepoint 2010 SPQuery to join two custom lists](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44372/sharepoint-2010-spquery-to-join-two-custom-lists)

[How to join two lists using REST API sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145925/how-to-join-two-lists-using-rest-api-sharepoint-2013)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are not much familiar with c#, for SharePoint and you have already created lookup field so for your expertise you use REST API to get the data of both list by expanding the fields of the list referred by lookup column. And also explained the referenced you mentioned.
[And for more understanding you can refer](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-csom-vs.-rest-...-my-preference-and-why)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to [comment on any post](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).